# core data syncing with iCloud

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode6, icloud

What I want to do is to sync `core-data` to `iCloud`. Currently I am able to store `core-data` locally.
I read apple docs about `Core-Data` and `iCloud` syncing, but I'm not able do to what they said.
What should I do to achieve this? I am a beginner in `iCloud`.

I also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012015/syncing-core-data-across-multiple-devices-using-icloud) but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SG_XSD84WOc

Comment: @DejanSkledar i want to do in Objective C

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25971816/xcode-6-ios-8-icloud-core-data-setup/26232010#comment45284278_26232010

Comment: What have you tried, and in what specific way did it not work? Saying you're "not able to do what they said" is not a useful question.